# Tricky MYSQL query dilema

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join, pymysql

So I have a tricky SQL query.

I have four tables:

- User table which contain information on my users
- Recipe table which contains information on a recipe such as the name, uploading user etc (not the ingredients)
- Recipe-user associative table to link all my ingredients to the recipes
- Ingredients table which holds all the ingredients that can be used

I want to create a function which downloads all this information in one go to display the users profile. This profile will consist of the users information - such as username and total recipes, with a tile view of the meals they have uploaded in a fashion similar to instagram.

So if you image the instagram user profile view:
[image: instagram profile view] 
you have the user information at the top and the images (in my case the recipes) below and when you tap a recipe you will see the list of ingredients. I want this however to be very responsive with no loading lag, hence the upfront loading of all the informaion.

Using joins this is of course not an overly difficult task, however what is produced is a messy list the length of the total number of ingredients.

I am using python with the pymysql module by the way.

I wonder if anyone has an ideas on the best possible way to go about this task?

Comment: split your data requests into the specific lists you need, keeping the data requested relevant.

Comment: Using "ORDER BY" could easily arrange your list in a better way. You could make some more complex queries using UNIONs to get user info in one row, & recipe names followed by ingredients in another. Or you could use python to sort the list as you want. Have you tried any of these so far?